# Error 404 page not found /profileScreen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, navigation-drawer, autorotate

I am using the flutter auto_route package for navigation. This error occurs when I navigate the screen on the context. e.g:
If I write

```
 ExtendedNavigator.named('BuyRouter').push(HomeRoutes.profileScreen);
```

This works and pushes on the BuyRouter screen but the problem I am having that I want to push the screen on context.
As I apply this to the context.

```
  ExtendedNavigator.root.push(HomeRoutes.profileScreen);
```

Error 404 page not found /profile screen occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ExtendedNavigator.of(context).push(HomeRoutes.profileScreen)
```

Resolved the issue.